# Weird mysql error, says "expects parameter", but mysql_error function returns nothing? Im lost

Tags: php, html, mysql, die

I am experiencing a weird mysql error. With the below text I am getting: `Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/chatterr/lr_bootstrap/profile.php on line 70` although  see nothing wrong with the code. I tried adding `die("Error in query: ".mysql_error());` above `if (mysql_num_rows($check_frnd_query) == 1 OR $user_id == $my_id) {` but that returned nothing. Im dumb founded by this problem. I may be looking over something. What do you think?

```
<?php 
ob_start(); 
include 'core/init.php'; 
include 'includes/overall/overall_header.php'; 

if (isset($_GET['username']) === true && empty($_GET['username']) === false) {
$username       = $_GET['username'];

if (user_exists($username) === true) {
    $my_id          = $session_user_id;
    $user_id        = user_id_from_username($username);
    $profile_data   = user_data($user_id, 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name',     'email', 'profile_img', 'bio');
    $user           = $user_id;
?>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <?php include 'includes/sidebar.php'; ?>
    <div class="span9">
      <div class="hero-unit">
        <p>
        <?php 
        if (empty($profile_data['profile_img']) === false) {

            echo '<img src="', $profile_data['profile_img'],'" alt="',     $profile_data['first_name'] ,'\'s Profile Image" class="profile">'; 
        }
        ?></p>
        <h2><?php echo $profile_data['first_name'],' ', $profile_data['last_name']; ?>    </h2>
        <p><?php echo $profile_data['bio']?></p>
        <p>

        <?php if($user_id === $session_user_id) {
        ?> <a href="settings.php">Edit Profile</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <?php
        } else {
        if (logged_in() === true) {
        if($user != $my_id){
        $check_frnd_query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM friends WHERE     (user_one ='$my_id' AND user_two='$user') OR (user_one='$user' AND user_two='$my_id')");

            if (mysql_num_rows($check_frnd_query) == 1) {
                echo "Friends | <a href='actions.php?    action=unfriend&user=$user' class='box'>Unfriend $username</a>";
            } else {
                $from_query = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM     `friend_req` WHERE `from`='$user' AND `to`='$my_id'");
                $to_query = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `friend_req`     WHERE `from`='$my_id' AND `to`='$user'");

                if(mysql_num_rows($from_query) == 1) {
                    echo "<a href='actions.php?    action=accept&user=$user' class='box'>Accept</a> | <a href='actions.php?action=ingnore&user=$user' class='box'>Ignore</a>";
                } else if (mysql_num_rows($to_query) == 1) {
                    echo "<a href='actions.php?action=cancel&user=$user' class='box'>Cancel Request</a>";
                } else {
                    echo "<a href='actions.php?    action=send&user=$user' class='box'>Send Friend Request </a>";
                }

            }
        }
        } //logged in
        } ?>

        <!-- If friends:
        <a>My Photos</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a>My Friends</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a>Message Me</a>
        </p>
        -->
        <!--<p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">My Profile &raquo;</a></p> --    >
      </div>
      <div class="row-fluid">
      <?php

      if (mysql_num_rows($check_frnd_query) == 1 OR $user_id == $my_id) {
      $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id=$user_id ORDER BY     timestamp DESC LIMIT 0, 3");

      while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        ?>
            <div class="span4">
              <h2><?php echo $profile_data['first_name']?> said...</h2>
              <h8><?php echo $row['timestamp']; ?></h8>
              <p><?php echo $row['content']; ?></p>
              <p><a class="btn" href="#">View Reactions &raquo;</a></p>
            </div><!--/span-->

        <?php
      }
      ?>
      </div><!--/row-->

      <div class="row-fluid">
      <?php
      $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id=$user_id ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 3, 6");

      while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        ?>
            <div class="span4">
              <h2><?php echo $profile_data['first_name']?> said...</h2>
              <h8><?php echo $row['timestamp']; ?></h8>
              <p><?php echo $row['content']; ?></p>
              <p><a class="btn" href="#">View Reactions &raquo;</a></p>
            </div><!--/span-->

        <?php
      }
      ?>
      </div><!--/row-->


    </div><!--/span-->
  </div><!--/row-->


<?php
} else {
    echo '<h3>Whoops, you must be friends with this user to see their posts.</h3>';
}

} else {
    header('Location: 404.php');
    exit();
}
} else {
header('Location: index.php');
exit();
}

include'includes/overall/overall_footer.php'; 
?>
```

This is what I am seeing: http://pbrd.co/Zo6sNb

Comment: try echo the query and running it in phpmyadmin and replace `mysql_query("SELECT id FROM friends WHERE     (user_one ='$my_id' AND user_two='$user') OR (user_one='$user' AND user_two='$my_id')");` with `mysql_query("SELECT id FROM friends WHERE     (user_one ='$my_id' AND user_two='$user') OR (user_one='$user' AND user_two='$my_id')") or die(mysql_error());` And start learning mysqli or pdo .. mysql functions are no longer maintained and are retarded

Comment: @new_developer The query is not the problem, i dont belive. Its something to do with `mysql_num_rows`

Comment: @new_developer Its still giving me the same error, even with your new query

Comment: mysql_num_rows is correct .. it returns this error when proper resource is not passed to it .. which means your query is not getting executed

Comment: How can I check that, I dont see any syntax errors that would lead to that

Comment: Check for errors after `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Which one is line 70?

Comment: @new_developer: the mysql functions are not "retarded". They're badly misused by uninformed developers. PDO is not a magical "zomg it's impossible to hack my code because I'm using PDO" pixie dust. PDO/mysqli code is just as easily subverted.

Comment: @MarcB The mysql extension is deprecated, it should not be used in new code. It's very likely that his problem would be alleviated if he used prepared statements with mysqli or PDO.

Comment: @barmar: deprecated doesn't mean "retarded". yes, it shouldn't be used anymore, but to issue a blanked "it's retarded" statement is even more retarded.

Comment: @Barmar Line 70 is: `if (mysql_num_rows($check_frnd_query) == 1 OR $user_id == $my_id) {`

Comment: @Barmar Am i checking it right this way? http://pasteboard.co/1dfZQXh3.png

Comment: You have quotes around an id field in the friends table, and no quotes in the posts table, maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Ugh, please don't use images for code. You're not checking right, you're checking `$result` but the variable is `$res`.

Comment: Okay, so I changed it to if (!$res) { and I got nothing not even the "invalid query" part, but then when i did: if (!$check_frnd_query) { it return the "invalid query" part but no error? If/when I get an error, it is: `Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/chatterr/lr_bootstrap/profile2.php on line 69`

Comment: All I know of what is causing this is because I am not my own friend, and even if I am it still give me the errors, but my other friends profiles there is no error, it it just my profile, or whichever account i am logged into's profile.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is probably failing and returning `FALSE` instead of a resource identifier which is anticipated by `mysql_num_rows`.

Always check for return value from `mysql_query` before passing it further.

```
$check_frnd_query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM friends WHERE     (user_one ='$my_id' AND user_two='$user') OR (user_one='$user' AND user_two='$my_id')");
if (!$check_frnd_query) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Thats not giving me anything? Here is my code: http://pbrd.co/Zo6Rzg and the out put still is: http://pbrd.co/Zo6SmI Idk why?

Comment: In your code you are assigning the result of `mysql_query` to a variable `$res` but checking variable `$result`. Change one or the other and try to run it again.

Comment: Okay, so I changed it to `if (!$res) {` and I got nothing not even the "invalid query" part, but then when i did: `if (!$check_frnd_query) {` it return the "invalid query" part but no error?

Comment: If/when I get an error, it is: `Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/chatterr/lr_bootstrap/profile2.php on line 69`

Comment: All I know of what is causing this is because I am not my own friend, and even if I am it still give me the errors, but my other friends profiles there is no error, it it just my profile, or whichever account i am logged into's profile.

Comment: You need to check after you execute your friend query. See updated answer.

Comment: The root problem is the same - failed query. Carefully put error checks after every `mysql_query` call using correct variables

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id=$user_id ORDER BY     timestamp DESC LIMIT 0, 3
```

In this query, user_id has no quotes, it's numeric?

```
SELECT id FROM friends WHERE     (user_one ='$my_id' AND user_two='$user') OR (user_one='$user' AND user_two='$my_id')
```

In this query, user_id type fields have quotes, it's a string?

Are you missing quotes in the first query?